# How can I benchmark packages of the golang standard library?

Tags: go

I'd like to make a small contribution the golang and need to run the benchmarks, e.g. for encoding/json.

All my attempts are failed (go1.13):

```
❯ go test -bench encoding/json
build .: cannot find module for path .

❯ go test encoding/json
ok      encoding/json   1.412s

❯ go test -bench std/encoding/json
build .: cannot find module for path .

❯ go test std/encoding/json
# std/encoding/json
package std/encoding/json (test)
        imports internal/testenv: use of internal package internal/testenv not allowed
FAIL    std/encoding/json [setup failed]
FAIL

❯ go test std
ok      archive/tar     (cached)

❯ go test -bench std
build .: cannot find module for path .
```

So how would I exclusively test encoding/json?

Comment: Do not install Go via brew.

Comment: You may want to coordinate your changes with Daniel Marti: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-dev/YMw7aBRvk-4/71YNDg73AQAJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a fresh checkout of the go source tree, after bootstrapping (i.e. running all.bash), go under go/src/ and run

```
 ../bin/go test ./encoding/json -bench=.
```

Or you can run it against the installed version the same way by going under /usr/local/go/src.

If you're planning to submit a performance enhancement, they'll want you to have before/after benchmarks comparisons. So run the benchmarks 10-20 times before and after, and compare the results using the `benchstat` tool.

```
../bin/go test ./encoding/json -bench=. -count=10 >after
```

Comment: You don't have to bootstrap, you can run the benchmarks/tests against a normal install of Go.

Comment: Yes, true. Let me fix that description

Comment: Your answer also only says how to run tests, which OP said were working for them. Benchmarks were the issue.

Comment: I didn't ask that but I still don't see how to run that against a normal go?

❯ go test ./encoding/json -bench=.
# std/encoding/json
package std/encoding/json (test)
        imports internal/testenv: use of internal package internal/testenv not allowed
FAIL    std/encoding/json [setup failed]
FAIL

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of go installed by any chance?

Comment: I have go installed via brew (on OSX) and go cloned outside ouf GOROOT. WFM inside GOROOT, much appreciated!

Comment: The dot in `./encoding/json` is  not needed.    `go clean -testcache && go test encoding/json -bench="."` must work

Comment: If you're trying to run it in the cloned go directory, then run the all script first, build the binary, and then run `../bin/go test ...`. That should not complain about the internal dir.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to Go modules, but what worked for me was to execute from within the stdlib:

```
cd /usr/local/go/src/encoding/json
go test -run='^$' -bench .
```

Comment: Doesn't work either:

imports internal/testenv: use of internal package internal/testenv not allowed

Comment: It worked fine for me. What version of Go are you using?